# Double Column CSS Dropdown Menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu

I am looking for Two column css drop down menu. Can you tell me the website where I can get the source code for this???

Example: If mouse over on the horizontal drop down menu, it should show two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed look on how to create your own dropdown menu in 2 columns. :-)

http://www.ehow.com/how_12008977_make-dropdown-menu-two-columns.html

Comment: I am looking for codes dirctly... can I get anywhere. There are plenty of websites for dropdown menu but not for double coloum menu